Button not staying disabled once form loads again
I'm creating a seat booking system for a college project. So I have this code and if the user selects a button/seat and clicks the write button it'll write that seat to the textfile. But if I close the form and load it again, the button does not stay disabled and I'm not sure what's wrong.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SearchFlights
{
    public partial class frmSeat : Form
    {
        private List<Button> selectedButtons = new List<Button>();
        private int maxSelectedButtons; // Adjust the maximum number of selectable buttons as needed

        public frmSeat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            button1.Click += Button_Click;
            button2.Click += Button_Click;
            button3.Click += Button_Click;
            button4.Click += Button_Click;
            button7.Click += Button_Click;
            button8.Click += Button_Click;
            button9.Click += Button_Click;
            button10.Click += Button_Click;
            button11.Click += Button_Click;
            button12.Click += Button_Click;
            button13.Click += Button_Click; //ECO 13-22
            button14.Click += Button_Click;
            button15.Click += Button_Click;
            button16.Click += Button_Click;
            button17.Click += Button_Click;
            button18.Click += Button_Click;
            button19.Click += Button_Click;
            button20.Click += Button_Click;
            button21.Click += Button_Click;
            button22.Click += Button_Click;
            textBox1.Text = "1";
            // ... add event handlers for other buttons
        }

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maxSelectedButtons = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    try
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

        // Check if the button has already been selected
        if (selectedButtons.Contains(clickedButton))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat already selected.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return; // Exit the method early
        }

        if (selectedButtons.Count < maxSelectedButtons)
        {
            // Display a message box with the button's text
            MessageBox.Show("You have selected: " + clickedButton.Text);
            selectedButtons.Add(clickedButton); // Keep track of selected buttons
        }
        else
        {
            // Maximum number of buttons reached
            MessageBox.Show("You can only select up to " + maxSelectedButtons + " seats.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter number of seats", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}



        private void frmSeat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            if (label2.Text == "First")
            {
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                button9.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
                button11.Enabled = false;  //1-4 FIST
                button12.Enabled = false;  //7-12 BUS
                button13.Enabled = false;  //13-22 ECO
                button14.Enabled = false;
                button15.Enabled = false;
                button16.Enabled = false;
                button17.Enabled = false;
                button18.Enabled = false;
                button19.Enabled = false;
                button20.Enabled = false;
                button21.Enabled = false;
                button22.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (label2.Text == "Business")
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;         //1-4 are first class
                button2.Enabled = false;         // 7,8 IS B   7-12
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button13.Enabled = false;  //13-22 ECO
                button14.Enabled = false;
                button15.Enabled = false;
                button16.Enabled = false;
                button17.Enabled = false;
                button18.Enabled = false;
                button19.Enabled = false;
                button20.Enabled = false;
                button21.Enabled = false;
                button22.Enabled = false;


            }
            if (label2.Text == "Economy")
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;  //1
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;// BUIS:
                button8.Enabled = false;
                button9.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
                button11.Enabled = false;
                button12.Enabled = false;

            }

            string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string relativePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Seats.txt");
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(relativePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                if ((label1.Text == values[0]) && (label2.Text == values[1]))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
                        {
                            if (button.Text == values[i])
                            {
                                button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                button.Enabled = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            /* string line;
             StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Global\Desktop\Seats.txt");

             using (sr)
             {
                 line = sr.ReadLine();
                 while (line != null)
                 {

                     string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                     if ((label1.Text == values[0]) && (label2.Text == values[1]))
                     {
                         for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                         {
                             foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
                             {
                                 if (button.Text == values[i])
                                 {
                                     button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                     button.Enabled = false;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     line = sr.ReadLine();
                 }




             }*/

        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            maxSelectedButtons = 0;
            foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (button.Text != "Reset")
                {
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                }


                // Reset any other properties or states of the buttons here
            }
            selectedButtons.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = "1";

            if (label2.Text == "First")
            {
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                button9.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
                button11.Enabled = false;  //1-4 FIST
                button12.Enabled = false;  //7-12 BUS
                button13.Enabled = false;  //13-22 ECO
                button14.Enabled = false;
                button15.Enabled = false;
                button16.Enabled = false;
                button17.Enabled = false;
                button18.Enabled = false;
                button19.Enabled = false;
                button20.Enabled = false;
                button21.Enabled = false;
                button22.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (label2.Text == "Business")
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;         //1-4 are first class
                button2.Enabled = false;         // 7,8 IS B   7-12
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button13.Enabled = false;  //13-22 ECO
                button14.Enabled = false;
                button15.Enabled = false;
                button16.Enabled = false;
                button17.Enabled = false;
                button18.Enabled = false;
                button19.Enabled = false;
                button20.Enabled = false;
                button21.Enabled = false;
                button22.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (label2.Text == "Economy")
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;  //1
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;// BUIS:
                button8.Enabled = false;
                button9.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
                button11.Enabled = false;
                button12.Enabled = false;
            }

            // string line;
            string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string relativePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Seats.txt");
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(relativePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                if ((label1.Text == values[0]) && (label2.Text == values[1]))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
                        {
                            if (button.Text == values[i])
                            {
                                button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                button.Enabled = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            /*  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Global\Desktop\Seats.txt");

              using (sr)
              {
                  line = sr.ReadLine();
                  while (line != null)
                  {

                      string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                      if ((label1.Text == values[0]) && (label2.Text == values[1]))
                      {
                          for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                          {
                              foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
                              {
                                  if (button.Text == values[i])
                                  {
                                      button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                      button.Enabled = false;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      line = sr.ReadLine();
                  }



              }*/

        }


        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //BACK BTN
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            frm2.Show();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //WRITE btn
            string id = label1.Text, clas = label2.Text;

            if (selectedButtons.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a seat.");
                return;
            }

            // Choose a file path (consider allowing user input)
            string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Seats.txt");
            

            try
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath,true);
                using (writer)
                {
                    writer.Write(id + "\t" + clas);
                    foreach (Button button in selectedButtons)
                    {
                        writer.Write("\t" +button.Text);
                    }
                   writer.Write("\t"+"-"+'\n');
                    
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Selected seats written to file: ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error writing to file: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}


When the form loads I tried this piece of code but it doesn't work:
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split('\t');
    if ((label1.Text == values[0]) && (label2.Text == values[1]))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (button.Text == values[i])
                {
                    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    button.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


if I close the form and load it again, the button does not stay disabled why does this surprise you?? if you want to persist something you not to DO it, e.g. by checking the textfile etc..
